# How to find largest element from an array?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve this assignment in C++ which has a given code and I have to complete. I'm stuck at the 2nd part, I cant find out what the while loop is doing there and don't know how I can write the code in there in order to find the largest element.

In this case I need largest element which I would get from the price `precios`, and then print out the code of the product which contains this price `codigoProducto`. As you can see `codigoProducto` is being counted in order to identify it by product 1, product 2, etc.

Can you please give me an idea of how I can accomplish this? thank you! (sorry for the Spanish)

```
int main() {
    double precios[5];
    int cantidades[5];

    int codPrecioMasAlto;
    int codCantidadMasBaja;
    double total = 0;
    int codigoProducto = 0;

    // 1.  ingreso de datos
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
        cout << "Ingresar precio de producto " 
             << codigoProducto++ << endl;
        cin >> precios[i];
        cout << "Ingresar cantidad del producto" << endl;
        cin >> cantidades[i];
    }

    // 2. cual de los productos tiene el precio mas alto
    while (codigoProducto < 5) {
        // completar el codigo
    }

    cout << "El producto con mayor precio es el Producto " 
         << codPrecioMasAlto << ", cuyo precio es " 
         << endl;
```

Comment: create a variable called max, set it to 0, each time in the loop compare element to max, if its larger then update max to that element.

Comment: @pm100 in this case, that variable would be codPrecioMasAlto. How would I compare it? codPrecioMasAlto < precios[i] ? What is the while loop supposed to do in there?

Comment: ok, so do the rest. Set it to 0, compare it with each element inside the loop, if element is larger them update MasAlto. I am not going to write the code for you. TRy something , if you get stuck update the question of post a new one

Comment: Please note that you increment `codigoProducto` 5 times in your `for` loop. When this loop is done, `codigoProducto` will be `5`. Then your `while` loop runs while `codigoProducto` is less than 5, so it will _never_ run.

Comment: Also, I understand you're probably not there yet in your education, but splitting related data across multiple separate arrays is generally an inferior solution to a single array of structs.

Comment: @Chris you are right, I will need to change this in order for codigoProducto have its own name, user could input it. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris I still have much to study, not sure what you mean :(

Answer (score 2):

Since this is C++, you can make use of the algorithms provided by the standard library.

```
    #include<algorithm>
    #include<iterator>
    
    ...

    double *precioMasAlto = std::max_element(std::begin(precios), std::end(precios));
```

This will give a pointer `precioMasAlto` to the largest element of the array. Thus the max price is `*precioMasAlto`.

If the index is needed, it can be calculated as the difference in position between the found element and the first element of the array (thanks to Jarod42 for noticing this solution):

```
std::distance(std::begin(precios), precioMasAlto);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to input information on five products, and then print out info on the highest priced item.

That might look something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string productNames[5];
    double productPrices[5];

    double maxPrice = 0.0;
    size_t indexForMaxPrice = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Input info for product " << (i + 1) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Name: ";

        std::cin >> productNames[i];

        std::cout << "Price: ";

        std::cin >> productPrices[i];

        if (productPrices[i] > maxPrice) {
            maxPrice = productPrices[i];
            indexForMaxPrice = i;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Most expensive item: " << productNames[indexForMaxPrice]
              << " at $" << productPrices[indexForMaxPrice]
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But, if we use a struct to group those related pieces of information, a naive approach might be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Product {
    std::string name;
    double price;
};

int main() {
    Product products[5];

    Product *maxPriceProduct = nullptr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Input info for product " << (i + 1) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Name: ";

        std::cin >> products[i].name;

        std::cout << "Price: ";

        std::cin >> products[i].price;

        if (maxPriceProduct == nullptr || products[i].price > maxPriceProduct->price) {
            maxPriceProduct = &products[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Most expensive item: " << maxPriceProduct->name
              << " at $" << maxPriceProduct->price
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```